# Normalize IDs column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I'm making a recommender system, and I'd like to have a matrix of ratings (User/Item).
 My problem is there are only 9066 unique items in the dataset, but their IDs range from 1 to 165201.
 So I need a way to map the IDs to be in the range of 1 to 9066, instead of 1 to 165201.
 How do I do that?

Comment: can't answer ATM.  Look into pandas.factorize

Comment: @piRSquared I couldn't use it. My dataset is in a pandas dataframe, I couldn't convert the itemID column to range from 1 to (number of unique items).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the dataframe `df`

```
np.random.seed([3,1415])
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
        User=np.random.randint(10, size=20),
        Item=np.random.randint(100, size=20)
    ))
print(df)

    Item  User
0     27     0
1     77     2
2     54     7
3     39     3
4     23     8
5     84     7
6     37     0
7     99     6
8     87     8
9     37     6
10    63     0
11    25     2
12    11     0
13    71     4
14    44     9
15    70     7
16     4     3
17    71     2
18    63     4
19    86     3
```

Use `unique` to get unique values and build a mapping dictionary

```
u = df.Item.unique()
m = dict(zip(u, range(len(u))))
```

Then use `map` to produce the re configured column

```
df.assign(Item=df.Item.map(m))

    Item  User
0      0     0
1      1     2
2      2     7
3      3     3
4      4     8
5      5     7
6      6     0
7      7     6
8      8     8
9      6     6
10     9     0
11    10     2
12    11     0
13    12     4
14    13     9
15    14     7
16    15     3
17    12     2
18     9     4
19    16     3
```

​Or we could have accomplished the same thing with `pd.factorize`

```
df.assign(Item=pd.factorize(df.Item)[0])

    Item  User
0      0     0
1      1     2
2      2     7
3      3     3
4      4     8
5      5     7
6      6     0
7      7     6
8      8     8
9      6     6
10     9     0
11    10     2
12    11     0
13    12     4
14    13     9
15    14     7
16    15     3
17    12     2
18     9     4
19    16     3
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go through and find the item with the smallest id in the list, set it to 1, then find the next smallest, set it to 2, and so on.

edit: you are right. That would take way too long. I would just go through and set one of them to 1, the next one to 2, and so on. It doesn't matter what order the ids are in (I am guessing). When a new item is added just set it to 9067, and so on.

Comment: That would take far too much time. Plus the whole process would need to be run again whenever a new item is added to the dataset.